# laravel join 3 table belongtomany

Tags: laravel

i have 3 tables and 1 tables pivot with 3 foreign keys , i want to show all artists name with theirs job for one media but i dont have any idea how about joinning those 3 tables

**Media table**: `media_id` , `media_title`

**artist table**: `artist_id`, `artist_name`

**job table**: `job_id`, `job_name`

**pivot table**: `media_id`, `artist_id`, `job_id`

I have tried to do with `belongsToMany` between them but no result, only show the artists name but can not get theirs job name for each

Thank you to much!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a92P.png]

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the relation between these tables?

I didn't really know what you want, but try this.

```
\DB::table('media_artist_job')
     ->join('media','media.media_id','=','media_artist_job.media_id')
     ->join('job','job.job_id','=','media_artist_job.job_id')
     ->join('artist','artist.artist_id','=','media_artist_job.artist_id')
     ->select([
         'media.medial_title',
         'job.job_name',
         'artist.artist_name'
     ])->where('media.media_id',/*The media id you want to retrieve*/)->get();
```

Hope it help!

Comment: thank you so much , can we use Eloquent: Relationships instead of Query Builder ?